# Protractor: Webdriver-manager update error

Tags: node.js, protractor, webdriver-manager

I installed JDK,NPM,Jode.js and protractor.
while updating webdriver-manager, i got this error ..

```
C:\Users\XYZ>webdriver-manager update

[11:01:00] I/file_manager - creating folder 
C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: certificate has expired

    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?